# Lubuntu stopped booting desktop, just goes to command line

Tags: command-line, nvidia, lubuntu, xorg

I was trying to get the text right on my TV monitor so I was messing with xorg.conf.
Well, I didn't see one so I ran the command `sudo nvidia-xconfig`.
That added the file so then I added `Options "DPI" "96x96"` to the 'monitor' section.
When I rebooted my desktop it asked for my username and pass, then went to a command line..
I have no idea what to do. I don't want to reinstall lubuntu and lose all of my things..
Did I royally screw up?

Comment: It's booting into tty1.

Comment: When I try startx it tells me that 'Options is not a valid keyword' inside my xorg.conf.
I'm gonna try to reinstall xorg

Comment: Nothing is working..

Answer (score 2):

1. Login to TTY1
2. Remove xorg.conf

   ```
   sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old1
   ```
3. Reboot

It should be `Option` without `s`

Comment: Okay! I just gave up and started copying all of my data over to my other drive. Once it gets done I'll try this! Thank you!!

Comment: It says that there's no such file or directory </3

Comment: @acollection_ , so which file did you edit?

Comment: The one that apparently doesn't exist -.-
I went into the directory and the only file that resembles xorg.conf is called xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original.
I ran the mv command on it and reset but it didn't work.

Comment: It's alright man. No use in stressing over this.. I'm just gonna reinstall lubuntu and make sure to not screw up the xorg.conf file this time.  
I appreciate your help. Everything just seems to be against us.

Comment: Lesson of the day.. Back up files.

Comment: @acollection_ :)  something goes wrong?

Comment: I got it working again. And what's weird is that I had my TV connected while I was installing and now everything is fine. No small text, nothing.
I did get that crash where the entire screen freezes and jumbles up like some kind of broken digital abstract painting but I hope that it doesn't happen a lot. It's all working now though. Fingers crossed that I don't get too many crashes (: